# Drag and drop a tab to the bookmarks in Chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome, bookmarks, drag-and-drop

I'm using Google Chrome on my work but at home I use Vivaldi. I really miss a feature there: you can drag a tab to the bookmarks in order to save it.

However, Google Chrome only creates a new window if its dragged which is very annoying, so, is there a way to do this behavior? (natively or via extension)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found the solution:

You can't drag the tab directly to the bookmarks but if you drag the **URL bar** it works perfectly!

Comment: For me it's not the bar, it's the text in the bar, but your hint helped my very very much.

I may call this bad design by Chrome...

Comment: When I've tested lately, dragging on the text doesn't work, but I can drag the lock icon to the left of the URL down into the bookmark bar (or into any bookmark folder that's on the bar).